# Union of generating sets is the generating set of the sum of the generated sets?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $(W_i)_{i\in I}$ be a (not necessarily finite) family of submodules of a $K$-module $E$. For each $i\in I$, let $S_i$ be the set that generates $W_i$. Does $\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ generate $\sum_{i\in I}W_i$?

Take $x\in\bigoplus_{i\in I}W_i$. Then $x_i=\sum_{s\in S_i}\alpha_{i,s}s$ for some $\alpha_i\in K^{(S_i)}$, for each $i\in I$. Thus $\sum_{i\in I}x_i=\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{s\in S_i}\alpha_{i,s}s$. But it's not clear how I can rewrite $\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{s\in S_i}\alpha_{i,s}s$ as a linear combination of elements of $\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$. Is this something that's even possible? Does anything change if I replace "module" by "vector space"?

**Edit:**

In order to show that $\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i$ generates $\sum_{i\in I}W_i$, we have to demonstrate a $\xi\in K^{(\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i)}$ such that $y=\sum_{s\in\bigcup_{i\in I}S_i}\xi_s s$, for each $y\in\sum_{i\in I}W_i$.

Let $I:=\{1,2,3\}$. Set $S_1:=\{a,b\}$, $S_2:=\{a,b,c\}$ and $S_3:=\{a,d\}$. Write $x_1:=\eta_{1a}a+\eta_{1b}b$, $x_2:=\eta_{2a}a+\eta_{2b}b+\eta_{2c}c$ and $x_3:=\eta_{3a}a+\eta_{3d}d$. Take $y:=x_1+x_2+x_3$. Then
$$y=\eta_{1a}a+\eta_{1b}b+\eta_{2a}a+\eta_{2b}b+\eta_{2c}c+\eta_{3a}a+\eta_{3d}d.$$
This shows that $\eta$ can never be transformed into an element of $K^{S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3}$ because its domain has more elements than $S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3=\{a,b,c,d\}$. One solution is to use
$$S_1\times\{1\}\cup S_2\times\{2\}\cup S_3\times\{3\}$$
instead of $S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3$ but then that won't give us an element of $K^{S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3}$. What can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and you're on the right track for showing it!

You're completely right that we write $x$ as a (finite!) sum of $x_i \in W_i$. Then we write each $x_i$ as a (finite) linear combination of the generators in $S_i$.

But now $x$ is a linear combination of (linear combinations of the generators). But that's the same thing as one large (but finite) linear combination of the generators!

It might be helpful to write out this argument writing

$$
x = 
(\alpha^1_1 s^1_1 + \ldots \alpha^1_n s^1_n) + 
(\alpha^2_1 s^2_1 + \ldots \alpha^2_m s^2_m) + 
\ldots +
(\alpha^k_1 s^k_1 + \ldots \alpha^k_l s^k_l)
$$

or something similar (importantly, *not* using $\sum$s). Here the $s^i$ are the generators for $W_i$.

Maybe that makes it more apparent that the $\{ s^i_j \}$ generate $\bigoplus W_i$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you please take a look at my edit?

Comment: Any time we work with multiple modules, we must assume their generators are disjoint sets for exactly this reason. It's not really an algebraic issue as much as a formalism related to how exactly we encode algebra inside set theory. I wouldn't worry about these kinds of pathologies -- you should always assume your generators are disjoint, and if you _want_ to identify generators, you have to quotient to make them equal.